# html, body click event except an element which has a focus function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show the options on focussing the input which I am able to achieve using the below jquery

HTML

```
<div class="form-field select-subject" id="valexp2_subject">
<span class="input-bkg input-bkg-select">
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Please select the subject">
</span>
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your subject is required.</span>
<div class="options">
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Loremp ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Dolor blah</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sit amet</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Consectetur blah </a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Adipiscing elit</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select-subject').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input').focus(function() {
      $(this).parents('.select-subject').find('.options').fadeIn();
      $('html').click(function() {
        if ($('.options').is(':visible') {
            //hide .options div
            }
            });
      });
    });
  });
```

CSS

```
.options {
 display: none;
}
```

When .options is visible and the user clicks on anywhere in `<html>` or `<body>` I need to hide the div. I tried multiple options but it's not going through. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean as below, i.e. when you `focus input` it `hide options` and on `blur` again `visible`,

> The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus.
>
> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select-subject').each(function() {
        $(this).find('input').focus(function() {
            $(this).parents('.select-subject').find('.options').fadeIn();
        });
    });
    $('.options li').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var selectValue = $(this).find('a').html();
            console.log(selectValue);
            $(this).parents('.select-subject').find('input').val(selectValue).focus();
            $(this).parents('.select-subject').find('.options').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
    $("#subject").on("focus",function(){
     $(".options").hide();
    });
    $("#subject").on("blur",function(){
     $(".options").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-field select-subject" id="valexp2_subject">
<span class="input-bkg input-bkg-select">
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Please select the subject">
</span>
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your subject is required.</span>
<div class="options">
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Loremp ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Dolor blah</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sit amet</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Consectetur blah </a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Adipiscing elit</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this jsFiddle, you can make use of e.preventDefault. which stop the default action from occurring https://jsfiddle.net/4Lsh5us2/1/, as you have added fadeOut on click so it hides that div.

Comment: <div class="options"> will be hidden when page loads. On focus of input, .options will be visible. While .options is visible and clicking on 'body' it should be hidden but this event should not get fired when clicking the input parent div.

Comment: Also cannot have #subject since I have 2 forms in the same page - Thanks

Comment: @swamysa Okay, but as said before that this could be achieved by stopping the bubbling of event to parent, as in this jsFiddle I have chained clicked and focus() event listener as both are performed on input, https://jsfiddle.net/d3o31hha/

Comment: Welcome @swamysa :-)